# targeting non angular iframe element within angular app

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I'm writing e2e tests for my angular app. The login is an external resource thats included via an iframe. For some of my tests I need my user to be logged in so I'm trying to target the iframe inputs to add credentials and login. Something like:

```
ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.switchTo().frame('loginIframe');
element(by.id('username')).sendKeys(username);
```

At this stage I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"message":"angular is not defined"....
```

I guess that because the iframe isn't an angular feature protractor falls over. Has anyone seen behaviour like this before? I thought that maybe it might be possible to use webdriver to target the elements rather than protractor.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 1):

Once you switch to a non-angular iframe, use

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'))
```

instead of

```
element(by.id('username'))
```

For more details visit: https://github.com/sakshisingla/Protractor-Non-Angular-Tests/wiki/Creating-test-scripts-using-Protractor-for-non-angular-application

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. I ended up having to create an instance of protractor and using it's .switchTo().frame() method

Comment: Great! In case the question is answered completely, then you can mark the Answer and close the post. In case something is still pending, then post here so that the post is answered completely!